# Retrieve & Display User Meta Values from Checkboxes

Tags: custom-taxonomy, user-meta

I need to create a page for team coach's to view player data from a custom post type.  Players are assigned to a "team" using a custom taxonomy called "team"

I have checkboxes setup for custom user meta which is dynamically populated by a custom taxonomy called "teams".

I need to display all checked options from the user's profile on a page with links to their corresponding taxonomy pages.

Ex.

[X] Team A

[X] Team B

[ ] Team C

[X] Team D

On the page it will then display the team Names (Ex. Team A) and permalink to each team if they are checked in the user's profile.

How can this be achieved?

**Function to create and save Custom User Meta Fields from Taxonomy**

```
function coach_team_access( $user ) {
    $teams = get_terms('team', array('hide_empty' => false));
    $user_teams = get_the_author_meta( 'user_teams', $user->ID );
    ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Team Access:</th>
            <td>
        <?php
        if ( count( $teams ) ) {
            foreach( $teams as $team ) { ?>
            <p><label for="user_iteams_<?php echo esc_attr( $team->slug); ?>">
                <input
                    id="user_teams_<?php echo esc_attr( $team->slug); ?>"
                    name="user_teams[<?php echo esc_attr( $team->term_id ); ?>]"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="<?php echo esc_attr( $team->term_id ); ?>"
                    <?php if ( in_array( $team->term_id, $user_teams ) ) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
                <?php echo esc_html($team->name); ?>
            </label></p><?php
            }
        } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'coach_team_access' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'coach_team_access' );

    // store access
    function coach_team_access_save( $user_id ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
            return false;
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_teams', $_POST['user_teams'] );
    }
    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'coach_team_access_save' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'coach_team_access_save' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your blank admin page that will house this info, using `add_menu_page()` or `add_submenu_page()`.

get your all the teams with `get_terms()` for later

get all players with `get_posts()`, and make a `foreach()` loop

within the loop, use `wp_get_post_terms()` to retrieve that players terms,

use the `get_terms()` value made earlier to loop through the list of teams.

add if statement to see if current player's has this term, then use`get_term_link()` to hyperlink, and mark it as checked